# How to Create form on the fly in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have requirement to create form on the fly  like html below

```
    <form action='http://www.example.com' method='POST' name=''>
<input type='HIDDEN' name='' value=''>
<input type='HIDDEN' name='Username' value=''>
<input type='HIDDEN' name='password' value=''>                          
<input type='SUBMIT' value='Go'>
    </form>
```

to  the form once this form  created it should automatically get post on page load in asp.net.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. It seems you want to do automatic login.The scenario you have given is hard to comprehend. Why you want to a post on server side? Form Posting is method of passing data from client to server.

Comment: ASP.NET can only have one form (unless you are using MVC). You can change this but it is not recommended. There is something fishy with what you are doing and I am sure there will be proper ways of doing it. Can you give more details

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is create the form on the fly with some data on the form and then submit this form on the the given url in the Action. and this should happnened on fly.
I dont want user to submit the form it should happened automatically

Comment: asp.net has its own form. do you want to add another form?

Comment: From the existing form it should create another form on the fly

Comment: are the controls going to change? I doubt that. The form there should be enough. You can have your controls in there and change the values from codebehind and then submit the form. On the fly in asp.net means `Page.Controls.Add(myControl)`

Answer (score 1):

This is can not actually post on PageLoad. You can post it automatically only using javascript after you have render the html page.

This article have a source code on how to create this form dynamically on asp.net and automatically make the post. Is done exactly what you ask for.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

From the previous answer by @Aristos, I have checked the link and I have learnt too. You can check it out

You can also use javascript to post the form when the page load

```
...your forms tags here

<script type="text/javascript">

   document.forms['form_name'].submit();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just  make sure the script is the last element in the DOM or use jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
   {
     document.forms['form_name'].submit();
   }
);
```